# How do I get mt-daapd?

Tags: server, music, itunes

I read other people's blog showing as easily as `sudo apt-get install mt-daapd`.  But when I do that, I got an error message `E: unable to locate package mt-daapd`.

Could someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
sudo apt-get install forked-daapd
```

### Quick tip

When you're searching for a package like this, try the following command:

```
apt-cache search keyword-here
```

So for instance,

```
apt-cache search daapd
```

Gives this:

```
forked-daapd - media server with support for RSP, DAAP, DACP and AirTunes
```